# AdMob ads are not showing in production on Android

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-admob

I'm using *cordova-plugin-admobpro* plugin to display ads inside my Cordova app. The test ads are showing if I set the *isTesting:true* property, but when i release my app to production (I removed isTesting:true property) the ads are not showing. The *onAdFailLoad* callback is fired and I get the following response:

```
{
"isTrusted":"false",
"adNetwork":"AdMob",
"adType":"banner",
"adEvent":"onAdFailLoad",
"error":"0",
"reason":"Internal error"
}
```

Anybody faced the same problem? I don't get why I get *isTrusted:false*. This means the app isn't trusted by Google or AdMob? How can I fix this?

I'm using cordova-plugin-admobpro 2.31.5 on Android.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My client set a bannerID to an Insterstitial Ad and an interstitialID to the banner Ad... So be careful with the Ad type when setting the IDs my fellow friends.

Answer (score 0):

in the past i had a similar problem. I forgot to save a payment method to admob. After adding this, everything worked as well.

Comment: Thanks for replying. My client set a banner AdMobID instead of a InterstitialID, that's why I got the isTrusted:false in production...